# C# Coding structure wrong, input (45 degrees) not outputting correct answer?

Tags: c#

I have some c# code (as below **) but I cannot seem to output the correct answer? The input is 45 (degrees) and the output should read 255.102 (meters), my answer is wrong as the output reads 413.2653.

I must confess that I think my code (structure) is actually wrong and not the arithmetic?

The whole code is as followed:

**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sums
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //prompt the user for angle in degrees
            Console.Write("Enter initial angle in degrees: ");
            float theta = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            //convert the angle from degrees to radians
            float DtoR = theta * ((float)Math.PI / 180);

            //Math.Cos
            DtoR = theta * (float)Math.Cos(theta);

            //Math.Sin
            DtoR = theta * (float)Math.Sin(theta);

            //t = Math.Sin / 9.8
            DtoR = theta / (float)9.8;

            //h = Math.Sin * Math.Sin / (2 * 9.8)
            DtoR = theta * theta / (2 * (float)9.8);

            //dx = Math.Cos* 2 * Math.Sin / 9.8
            DtoR = theta * 2 * theta / (float)9.8;

            //result
            Console.Write("Horizontal distance {0} Meters. \r\n ", DtoR, theta);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know that assign `DtoR` - five time?

Comment: You are overwriting `DtoR` on each calculation. `DtoR`'s value will be whatever the last line calculates.

Comment: @Green, are you familiar with using the `Debugger`..? this is something that you can easily fix as well as find on your own if you know how to use the tools that are at your disposal.. please debug your own code first.. you are overwriting your `DtoR` come on now..

Comment: Maybe you could include the mathematical formula you are trying to recreate.

Answer (score 1):

Well both, structure and arithmetics seem wrong.

You convert the entered value from degree to radians in that line:

```
float DtoR = theta * ((float)Math.PI / 180);
```

So now `DtoR` has the correct radians value. But **you don't use** it as we can see in that line:

```
 DtoR = theta * (float)Math.Cos(theta /* <- this is wrong! */);
```

`Math.Cos` expects radians, but you pass `theta` which still holds the degree value. And you do this in the following lines, too.

The **second** problem is, you don't use any of the results! The value of `theta` never changes, because you don't assign any value to that. You only assing values to `DtoR` but don't use these values except the last one.

In the last line, you output `DtoR` (you pass `theta` too, but it's not in the format string). This is the `DtoR` value you just calculated in the line before using the original `theta` value as entered by the user.

From your comments (in the code), I try to rewrite your code:

```
//convert the angle from degrees to radians
float DtoR = theta * ((float)Math.PI / 180);

//Math.Cos
float cos = (float)Math.Cos(DtoR);

//Math.Sin
float sin = (float)Math.Sin(DtoR);

//t = Math.Sin / 9.8
float t = sin / (float)9.8;

//h = Math.Sin * Math.Sin / (2 * 9.8)
float h = sin * sin / (2 * (float)9.8);

//dx = Math.Cos* 2 * Math.Sin / 9.8
float dx = cos * 2 * sin / (float)9.8;

//result
Console.Write("Horizontal distance {0} Meters. \r\n ", dx)
```

**Note** that I just converted what you already did. It seems to me that there are some more flaws in your algorithm.

Comment: I'm guessing that `t` and `h` really should be used to calculate `dx` somehow.

Comment: @juharr I leave the rest up to OP as homework, which it probably is anyway. S/He asked for the code problems, not the science.